# How to check if a pattern of rows is missing in a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below sample dataframe. Each hour has 5 instances. Is there any module or a way to find the missing data in a given column in Python.
For instance for hour 2, instance 3 is missing. How can we identify this missing instance in a larger dataset dynamically in Python and print a message that an instance is missing.

```
Date          Hour  Instance 
2022-10-20     1      1 
2022-10-20     1      2
2022-10-20     1      3
2022-10-20     1      4
2022-10-20     1      5
2022-10-20     2      1
2022-10-20     2      2 
2022-10-20     2      4
2022-10-20     2      5
```

Thank you.

Comment: Aggregate to determine the unique value counts of `Instance` for each hour. Filter for hours whose value counts are not 5. Next, create two lists - unique Dates and unique Hours. Now aggregate over each Instance. Wherever the count is off, that's the Date/Hour with a missing pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['Hour'], df['Instance'])

out = df2[df2.eq(0)].stack().reset_index()[['Hour', 'Instance']]
```

Output:

```
   Hour  Instance
0     2         3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
(df.set_index(["Hour", "Instance"])
   .unstack()
   .isna().where(lambda fr: fr)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   [["Hour", "Instance"]])
```

- move Hour & Instance pairs to the index
- then unstack the last one, i.e., Instance

  - this will have a reindexing effect on hours: all of them will have 1 to 5
  - and the missing ones will be marked as NaN
- now mask the non-NaNs to become NaN, and NaNs to be True...
- ...because when stack'ed, NaNs will go and only original missings will present
- move Hour & Instance back to columns and select them to show the desired pairs

to get

```py
   Hour  Instance
0     2         3
```

Meaning, there was only 1 instance missing, and it was Hour 2's Instance 3.

Answer (score 0):

First, define a function that checks if there is a missing instance.

```
def is_data_missing(array):
    """Return True when data is missing, ie array is different from range."""
    return list(array) != list(range(1, len(array) + 1))
```

Then you can apply it to your DataFrame, grouping by hour first.

```
>>> df.groupby("Hour").apply(lambda x: is_range(x["Instance"].values))
Hour
1    False 
2     True
```

The resulting DataFrame gives you the hours when data was missing. You can then iterate through the items to print a message.

```
>>> for hour, is_missing in df_missing.items():
...     if is_missing:
...         print(f"At hour {hour} data is missing")
At hour 2 data is missing
```